# How to implicitly animate changes in a list (AnimatedList won't work)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a signup form and I need to display a list of input errors under the username field (can't contain a character, username taken, etc). The list is created in a provider that notifies every time the list changes.

The provider doesn't say that a particular row has been inserted or removed, just gives me a new updated list, so I can't use AnimatedList.

This is my code:

```
ValueListenableBuilder<List<String>>(
  valueListenable: model.usernameErrorNotifier,
  builder: (context, errors, _) {
    return ErrorList(errors); // Figuring this out
  },
),
```

How can I implement the `ErrorList` so that it can implicitly animate the differences between the old and new lists?

Or is there a better way?